# Regexp regular/recursive find/replace in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++, regexp-replace

How to split some strings defined in a specific format:

```
[length namevalue field]name=value[length namevalue field]name=value[length namevalue field]name=value[length namevalue field]name=value
```

Is it possible with a Find/Replace regex in Notepad++ isolate the pair name=value replacing [length namevalue field] with a white space?
The main problem is related to numeric value where a simple \d{4} search doesn't work.

---

Eg.

INPUT:

```
0010name=mario0013surname=rossi0006age=180006phone=0014address=street
0013name=marianna0013surname=rossi0006age=210006phone=0015address=street1
0003name=pia0015surname=rossini0005age=30017phone=+39221122330020address=streetstreet
```

OUTPUT:

```
name=mario surname=rossi age=18 phone= address=street
name=mario surname=rossi age=18 phone= address=street
name=marianna surname=rossi age=21 phone= address=street1
name=pia surname=rossini age=3 phone=+3922112233 address=streetstreet
```

Comment: Try `\d{4}(?=[[:alpha:]]\w*=)` (or `\d{4}(?=[^\W\d]\w*=)`)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you for the feedback. It seems to work. Can you give me more details about the regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
\d{4}(?=[[:alpha:]]\w*=)
\d{4}(?=[^\W\d]\w*=)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aniiAb/1).

The patterns match

- `\d{4}` - four digits
- `(?=[[:alpha:]]\w*=)` - that are immediately followed with a letter and then any zero or more word chars followed with a `=` char immediately to the right of the current position.
- `(?=[^\W\d]\w*=)` - that are immediately followed with a letter or an underscore and then any zero or more word chars followed with a `=` char immediately to the right of the current position.

In Notepad++, if you want to remove the match at the start of the line and replace with space anywhere else, you can use

```
^(\d{4}(?=[[:alpha:]]\w*=))|(?1)
```

and replace with `(?1: )`.  The above explained pattern, `\d{4}(?=[[:alpha:]]\w*=)`, is matched and *captured* into Group 1 if it is at the start of a line (`^`), and just matched anywhere else (`(?1)` recurses the Group 1 pattern, so as not to repeat it). The `(?1: )` replacement means we replace with empty string if Group 1 matched, else, we replace with a space.

See the demo screenshot:

[image]